# Why doesn't $thousands_sep work to remove comma?

Tags: php, number-formatting

I have a serious problem.  My page is performing a simple formula to update a price if the item should be on sale.

```
<?php if(isset($row_Brand['Sale'])) 
      { 
         $YourPrice = ($row_Brand['Sale'] * number_format($row_Recordset1['Price'], 2, '.', ''));
      } 
      else 
      { 
         ($YourPrice = number_format($row_Recordset1['Price'], 2, '.', '')); 
      } 
  ?>
```

The value of Price is 1,549.00. However the number format is making it 1.00 using the code above.  Hence the result is way off.  This is a serious issue and I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `number_format()` cannot parse a number with a comma in it. You can fix that with `str_replace(',', '', $row_Recordset1['Price'])`, then do a `number_format()` on the number.

```
if(isset($row_Brand['Sale'])) 
{ 
     $YourPrice = ($row_Brand['Sale'] * number_format(str_replace(',', '', $row_Recordset1['Price']), 2, '.', ''));
} 
else 
{ 
     ($YourPrice = number_format(str_replace(',', '', $row_Recordset1['Price']), 2, '.', '')); 
}
```